# OpenLDAP search filter to get groups of a user in Ping Federate

Tags: ldap, openldap, pingfederate

I am able to get group of a user to which the user belong to. I can get this only if the user is assigned to one group. I am using the following search filter to get groups:

&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=cn=${username},ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com)

This filter works perfectly in openLDAP ldapsearch. But in Ping federate, it gives me null when I try to get more than 1 group for a user.

Please let me know if there is any other approach to achieve.

Thanks,
Aswini J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this not possible using OpenLDAP because your filter is returning more than 1 object (multiple groups each with a unique DN). If you look at your OpenLDAP logs, it is most likely returning a "sizelimit exceed" message to PingFederate because PF is explicitly instructing the LDAP server to only return 1 object. This is a common issue when using PingFederate with Directories other than Active Directory and returning lists of groups. You can see more info here on this type of error -

https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA340000000GsD6CAK

If OpenLDAP has the ability to manage Groups and Group Memberships in a similar fashion to AD, you should be able to return a list of Groups to PingFederate as you are trying to do.